# How to know if Javascript append method has completed with script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, browser, callback

```
var js_1 = "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xxxx.yyy.appl.js"> </script>" 

var js_2 = <script type="text/javascript">JUMBO.submission.onComplete(function(response) { alert('hello'); console.log(response); }); </script>

    $('.form-section').append(js_1);  ---> line 3 
    $('.form-section').append(js_2);  ---> line 4
```

In normal scenario `JUMBO` object should be defined after `appl.js` is initiated, but in my scenario i get error saying `JUMBO` is not defined.

**My findings:** 
If it was regular `append` method, as it is synchronous calls, it wouldn't be a problem but as the `js_1` is async call, before this `line 3`is getting executed, `line 4` is getting executed and getting error.

I have tried `$.getScript, Deferred` methods to solve it but no luck. Any help would be rewarded.

NOTE:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xxxx.yyy.appl.js"> </script>"` have to be inserted into the DOM such that it will generate the required html.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback argument to `$.getScript`

```
$.getScript("https://xxxx.yyy.appl.js", function() {
    JUMBO.submission.onComplete(function(response) { 
        alert('hello'); 
        console.log(response); 
    });
});
```

The callback will be executed after the script has been loaded.

Comment: That's essentially how `$.getScript` works, it adds a script element to the DOM.

Comment: Actually [`jQuery.getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) fires the callback "once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed", so `JUMBO` may still be undefined. AFAIK only Firefox features [event `afterscriptexecute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/afterscriptexecute), which would be the definite indicator that `JUMBO` is defined. When this event is not provided, I usually put a short timeout to give a chance for the script to execute…

Comment: @Barmar hmmm but `$.getScript` using this its not generating html like it generates with `.append` ..if this generates html ..it would be awesome